# How to transfer value from one component to another using input/output in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on my Angular 8 project and I want to transfer value from one component to another when the user clicks on the button.

I have used the service method to transfer the value from one component to another when the user clicks on the button. It is working fine but I think this method is not good for transferring.

This is my **Service: myservice.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {
  value1: Boolean = true;
  value2: Boolean = false;

  private messageSource1 = new BehaviorSubject(this.value1);
  private messageSource2 = new BehaviorSubject(this.value2);
  currentMessage1 = this.messageSource1.asObservable();
  currentMessage2 = this.messageSource2.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changevalue(chvalue1: boolean, chvalue2: boolean) {
    // return this.value1 = false;
    this.messageSource1.next(chvalue1);
    this.messageSource2.next(chvalue2);
  }

}
```

In this service, I have added the `changevalue` function which is used by the other components.

This is my **headcomp.component.html**:

```html
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-md-8 no_padding">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./assets/images/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 no_padding" style="margin-top: 4px;">
        <div class="logo">
            <nav>
                <a routerLink="/loginpage" (click)="myclick2()" *ngIf="svalue1" class="mya2">Login</a>
                <a routerLink="/registerpage" (click)="myclick2()" *ngIf="svalue1" class="mya2">Register</a>
                <a [routerLink]="[{outlets: {dashboard: ['frontpage']}}]" (click)="myclick()" *ngIf="svalue1" class="mya2">Other Page</a>
                <a (click)="myclick2()" *ngIf="svalue2" class="mya2">Logout</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my header component in which I have added the buttons on which the click function works.

This is my **headcomp.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from '../../Service/myservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-headcomp',
  templateUrl: './headcomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./headcomp.component.css']
})
export class HeadcompComponent implements OnInit {

  svalue1: any;
  svalue2: any;
  constructor(public myapi: MyserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myapi.currentMessage1.subscribe(svalue1 => this.svalue1 = svalue1);
    this.myapi.currentMessage2.subscribe(svalue2 => this.svalue2 = svalue2);
    console.log('currentMessage1', this.svalue1, this.svalue2 );
  }

  myclick() {
    this.myapi.changevalue(false, true);
    console.log('Event Clicked1', this.svalue1, this.svalue2 );
  }

  myclick2() {
    this.myapi.changevalue(true, false);
    console.log('Event Clicked2', this.svalue1, this.svalue2 );
  }

}
```

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from './Service/myservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // @Input() message: boolean;
  constructor(public myapi: MyserviceService) {
    // this.myapi.currentMessage1.subscribe(rsvalue1 => this.rsvalue1 = rsvalue1);
    // this.myapi.currentMessage2.subscribe(rsvalue2 => this.rsvalue2 = rsvalue2);
  }
  title = 'Batchproject1';
  rsvalue1: any;
  rsvalue2: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myapi.currentMessage1.subscribe(rsvalue1 => this.rsvalue1 = rsvalue1);
    this.myapi.currentMessage2.subscribe(rsvalue2 => this.rsvalue2 = rsvalue2);
    console.log('App Component', this.rsvalue1, this.rsvalue2 );
  }

}
```

This is my **app.component.html:**

```html
 <div class="main_wrapper">
   <div class="container no_padding">
     <app-headcomp></app-headcomp>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In this Html, I have added the header component selector.

In this, I am transferring the value from one component to another when the user clicks on the button in the header component using the service. But I think, this is not an efficient way.

Can anyone suggest me how to make it efficient or transfer the value using input/output in Angular 8?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `HeadcompComponent` you should set a `EventEmiter` as your Output.

```js
export class HeadcompComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() public myAction: EventEmitter<MyData> = new EventEmitter<
     MyData
  >();
  ...

  YOUR OTHER CODE

  ...

  myclick() {
    ...
    const data: MyData;

    this.myAction.emit(data); 
  }
}
```

In your `app.component.html` you have to call the created EventEmitter-Output, (Note that is has the same name: `myAction`). There you pass a callback, that ist a method of your `AppComponent`

```html
 <div class="main_wrapper">
   <div class="container no_padding">
     <app-headcomp (myAction)="doSomething($event)"></app-headcomp>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In Your AppComponent, `doSomething()` will be called receiving your data as argument:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  doSomething(data: MyData): void {
     ...
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your component ts file declare a variable and add `@Input()` to let them component receive the value of this variables from outside

your component.ts

`import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
 @Input() title: string;`

your main component HTML (where your component id used )

`<my-component [title]="im title"></my-component>`

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain according to the question?

Comment: headcomp.component.ts:
`import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter , Input } from'@angular/core';`

now put  `@Input()` before any variable that you want to get the value of it from outside of component for example `@Input() title: string;`

app.component.html:

` <div class="main_wrapper">
   <div class="container no_padding">
     <app-headcomp [title]="in here you can data to title variable in your headcomp component "></app-headcomp>
   </div>
 </div>`
if you put it like `[title]` then you have to assign variable and if you put it like `title` you can assign values